# In Phonegap + IOS button click event fire multiple times using iScroll 4

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, iscroll4, iscroll

I am using `iScroll` v4 in Phonegap 2.1.0 + IOS. I have a two iscroll in two different pages.

**First iscroll**

```
function locationload() {
    locationScroll = new iScroll('locationWrapper', {
        vScrollbar: false,
        hScrollbar: false,
        hScroll: false
    });   
}
```

**Second iscroll**

```
function preferenceload() {
    preferencesScroll = new iScroll('preferencesWrapper', {
        vScrollbar: false,
        hScrollbar: false,
        hScroll: false
    });
}
```

In first page `iScroll` worked fine. Second page `iScroll` also worked fine. but when i click a button in second page, button click event fire multiple times. If i remove the iScroll in second page, button click event works fine. I am using **$.mobile.changePage("#Page2", null, true, true);** to navigate to Page2.

I can't find any solution anywhere so I am hoping someone here can throw me some ideas.

Thanks

Comment: are you using jQuery Mobile?

Comment: there are lots of questions about this related to JQM - from what I have experienced, they way to do this is `$('element').unbind("click").click( function()
    {
        //click code
    });`

Comment: @whodeee Yes I use jQuery Mobile.

Comment: With what @whodeee said, try to destroy the iScroll after navigation away from the view.

Comment: I have similar problem trying to use jQM tap, unbinding, trying to stop propagation and even using other JS libraries like hammer.js. so far nothing work and investing time researching people face similar problems and from what other says it is a very old bug even present in the latest jQM versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try [jquery-mobile-iscrollview](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview)